# How do I install Ubuntu on VirtualBox on Mac? (OS X El Capitan)

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, mac, macosx

I just downloades Ubuntu 14.04.3 (1GB) and I don't know exactly what to do next. Can someone please explain in detail what should I do. I also downloaded Virtual Box. Thank you so much for taking your time to answer :)

Comment: It would be helpful to know whether you want to *replace* your Mac OS, set up a *dual boot* (choose which system during startup), or install Ubuntu into the Virtual Box you downloaded.  The processes are very different.

Comment: @ZeissIkon: Do you have a guide/resource to install Ubuntu on the VirtualBox instead of the dual boot ? I think the answer posted here is the config for dual boot!

Answer (score 6):

Following is the step-by-step guide for you to install Ubuntu on VirtualBox on Mac OSX:

1. At first open your VirtualBox app. When VirtualBox opens, click the New button.

[image]

2. Give your “**virtual machine**” a name (something descriptive is good, but it doesn’t matter). Make sure the Type: is set to **Linux** and the Version: is **Ubuntu (64 bit)**. Then click the **Continue** button.

[image]

3. Now you’re going to decide how much **memory (RAM)** you’re going to allocate to Ubuntu when it’s running, and how much to leave for OS X. As illustrated in the screenshot below, my total RAM is 4GB, so I allocated half of it to Ubuntu, and the other half to OS X. The more memory you give to Ubuntu, the faster it will run. The drawback is that OS X will have less to use while Ubuntu is running. At a minimum, give Ubuntu at 1GB (1024MB) of RAM. When you’ve decided how much memory (RAM) to give Ubuntu, click the Continue button.

[image]

4. On the **Hard drive** screen, select **Create a virtual hard drive now** and then click **Create**.

[image]

5. Now select **VDI (VirtualBox Disk Image)** and click **Continue**

[image]

6. Select **Dynamically allocated** and yep – you guessed it – click **Continue**

[image]

7. Give the “**VirtualBox Disk Image**” a name (again, doesn’t really matter, but descriptive is always helpful). Use the “**slider**” to determine the size you want to make the “hard drive” for Ubuntu. At a minimum, you’ll want to select 6GB – and that will not allow for you to install many programs, let alone store files etc. Keep in mind that because you selected “**Dynamically allocated**” in the previous step, that does not mean that VirtualBox is going to take up that space right away. It means that as Ubuntu needs more space, it will allow the “hard drive” to increase up to whatever size you set at this step.
   As illustrated in the screenshot below, I opted to give Ubuntu 8GB. That’s enough for the installation and to install quite a few programs. If you have a big hard drive, you might as well allocate more rather than less, again – the space won’t be used until it’s needed. After you’ve made your selection, click **Create**.

[image]

8. Almost time to install Ubuntu! Click the **Start** button.

[image]

9. Right away you’ll be prompted to locate a file. Click the “**folder**” icon next to menu that says **Empty** (see screenshot below).

[image]

10. Navigate to the **Ubuntu .iso** file that you downloaded. Select it, and click **Open**

[image]

11. Now click **Start**

[image]

12. As Ubuntu boots for the very first time, VirtualBox will ‘**pop up**’ little messages explaining how the keyboard and mouse will work with your new ‘virtual machine’. Read them, then click the little X to close them.

[image]

13. Finally! Click **Install Ubuntu**

[image]

14. Ubuntu will run a quick test to ensure your computer is capable of running on it. Once it’s passed those tests, make sure to place a check in both of the boxes – **Download updates while installing** and **Install this third-party software** – then click the **Continue** button.

[image]

15. Select **Erase** disk and install Ubuntu. NOTE: this is not going to ‘wipe out’ or erase any data in OS X. None. It is safe to click **Install Now**, so do just that.

[image]

16. Click **Continue**

[image]

17. When prompted, select your **Time Zone** and then click **Continue**

[image]

18. Select **the keyboard layout and language** you want, then **Continue**

[image]

19. Fill in each field with the **required** information. When you’re done, **Continue**

[image]

20. Now it’s time to sit back and relax with that cup of coffee or tea. This may take a bit.

[image]

21. Yay! It’s done! Click **Restart Now**

[image]

22. If Ubuntu doesn’t start loading, and you’re left at a screen with what looks a bit like gibberish, have no fear. Click the OS X “**Close**” button (the red one in the upper left corner).

[image]

23. Select **Power off the machine** and click **OK**. You’ll be left back at the main VirtualBox window. Just click the **Start** button again.

[image]

24. And you’ll boot into Ubuntu! Enter your password when prompted.

[image]

25. Welcome to the **Ubuntu Desktop**! At this point you should be connected to the Internet and completely ready to go – have fun!

[image]

Comment: @marianasotogiraldo: does it help you?